# What is a good search for zips by radius API or Node.js Module for the world?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, zipcode

So I am having trouble with this actually. Originally I found a npm module called zip codes. Does exactly what I want in terms of functionality with a little extra, however it only works for the USA. After being disappointed I searched npm and couldn't find anything like it that would include US, Europe, or the rest of the world. So then I figured, well Google should have an api. Well they actually don't.The best I was able to do was get a zip code with lat and long coordinates. I been searching for about a week, and so far I fear that I would have to create a database to do coordinate searching. I'm just hoping that there is another solution than having to do that. But it's possible I been searching the wrong thing. Most of my searches did include zip code lookup or geo zip codes by radius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try getting postal_code instead of ZIP code. As differentiated [here](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/844/~/whats-the-difference-between-zip-code-and-postal-code.):

> The two codes are essentially the same in their purpose, but the term Zip code is mainly used in the USA; Postal Code is commonly used in other countries.

For this, I suggest that you try the given options then see the differences so you may choose what suits your needs.

You may try the two following processes which [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) service provides:

- **Geocoding** is the process of converting addresses (like a street address) into geographic coordinates (like latitude and longitude), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map.
- **Reverse geocoding** is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address.

Requests using these processes possibly returns **`postal_code`** You may check [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036508/get-address-and-zipcode-with-longitude-and-latitude-in-google-map) to see sample code implementations or to learn more about Geocoding API service.

Lastly, for the Node.js, you may want to check these links:

- [Perfecting the Basic Node.js App](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/perfecting-the-basic-nodejs-app)
- [problem coding node.js extra credit challenge forecast.io command line app](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/problem-coding-nodejs-extra-credit-challenge-forecastio-command-line-app)

Comment: So searching postal codes allowed me to find queries on geolocation. So now all I have to do is store the lat and long points and google can get me the search of the user input postal codes. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote this npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/zipcodes-nearby

I believe that is what you are looking for.  You provide the zipcode to search around and a zipcode CSV file w/ Longitude and Latitude and you get a list of zipcode within a given radius back.

Although I called zipcode it can used for postal code or anything else as long as you have a CVS file w/ coordinates